# [android]gridview with image and text dynamically added

Tags: android

I want to make an application in which i don't have any XML files.
Image and text for the grid view is dynamically added and I want it looks like text is above image.. And I want it in all..You can say it looks like gallery with having name of images above the image.

So please help me..

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: See this link: http://alltechsolution.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/gridview-with-image-and-textview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Finally I made it on my own. And sharing to all if some one want to use it.

package com.example.customlayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    int i,j;
    int counter=0;
    boolean flag=false;
    int tid=55523,cid=25;
    int imid=55423,l_id=0;
    SharedPreferences settings;
    String [] values= new String[]{"Sample1","Sample2","Sample3","Sample4","Sample5","Sample6","Sample7","Sample8","Sample9","Sample10","Sample11","Sample12","Sample13","Sample14","Sample15","Sample16","Sample17","Sample18","Sample19","Sample20"};
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2,
            R.drawable.sample_3, R.drawable.sample_4,
            R.drawable.sample_5, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2,
            R.drawable.sample_3, R.drawable.sample_4,
            R.drawable.sample_5, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,

    };
    int pos=0;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> check = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ScrollView sc = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
        sc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for( i = 0;i<10;i++)
        {
            final LinearLayout ll1 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            ll1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            ll1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            for(j = 0;j<2;j++)
            {

                ll1.addView(rowView(getApplicationContext()));
            }
            ll.addView(ll1);
        }
        sc.addView(ll);
        this.setContentView(sc);
    }

    private View rowView(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WindowManager mWinMgr = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        int displayWidth = mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        final LinearLayout ll1 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        ll1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((displayWidth/2), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll1.setId(l_id);

        final LinearLayout ll2 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        ll2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((displayWidth/2), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        ll2.setId(l_id);


        final TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setId(tid--);
        tv.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        tv.setText(values[pos]);

        final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());

        cb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        cb.setId(cid--);
        cb.setTag(counter);

        for(int x = 0 ; x < check.size(); x++)
        {

            if(check.contains(counter))
            {
                cb.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
        counter++;

        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked){
                    Integer pos1= (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    check.add(pos1);
                    Log.i("TAG_3", ""+pos1);

                }else{
                    Integer pos2= (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    if(check.contains(pos2))
                    {
                    check.remove(pos2);
                    Log.i("TAG", ""+pos2+"removed");
                    }

                }
            }
        });


        final ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
        img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        img.setId(imid--);
        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        img.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        img.setImageResource(mThumbIds[pos]);

        pos++;
        /*Log.i("Demo", ""+pos);
        Log.i("TAG", ""+i);
        Log.i("TAG1", ""+j);
        Log.i("TAG2", ""+tid);
        Log.i("TAG3", ""+imid);*/

        ll2.addView(cb);
        ll2.addView(tv);
        ll1.addView(ll2);
        ll1.addView(img);
        ll1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID of TextView is:"+ String.valueOf(tv.getId())+" \t ID of Imageview is:"+ String.valueOf(img.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
            }


        });
        l_id++; 

        return ll1;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why you need this, even without having(single xml file) main.xml. Here are the steps you need to follow.

1. Create your layout dynamically by LayoutParams like the following.

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ```
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           LayoutParams params=new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
           GridView layout=new GridView(this);
           layout.setNumColumns(9);
           layout.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));

       }
   ```
2. Now you define the CustomAdapter class according to your requirement. As you said you need the text above the image, so your each grid item should now contain a textview with image. This grid item can be acheived with a linearlayout with **setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)**  and add all such type of items to your gridview.

This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) can give you basic idea how to create custom adapter class. But in your case you define your grid items too dynamically rather than in xml. I just gave you the suggestion to achieve your requirement, as it is difficult to others to write your required code completely.