# Trying to set Text on an ImageButton or equivalent

Tags: android, android-button, imagebutton

So, I already know that you cannot put text on an imageButton, but that is ultimately what I want to do.  I have a multiple choice-type activity where there's question and 4 answers to tap on.  Now, sometimes the answer is an image, and sometimes it's text.  What is the best way to put text over these buttons for the text answers?

Right now the only thing I can think of is putting 4 regular button in the same spot, and making them invisible as needed (which probably wouldn't be hard) but it feels like I'm fighting the android rules and it seems kind of tedious.

Is there a known easier way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Use radiogroup for selecting an answer? use imageview and text view for choices. That's the regular practice.

Comment: @sanjeev radiogroup isn't really what I'm looking for.  I have 4 big buttons underneath the question and the user taps on the answer rather than check a radiogroup bubble

Comment: you can dynamically add the views like image or text even the layout you can refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12706063/8040930)

Comment: But why button? A button is usually used for executing a function or move to different activity. It is not advised to use a button just for selecting an answer unless you want to execute some function(which can also be done by imageview or textview).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your case.
You should not hard-code your 4 answers.
What you need is to create a recyclerView to hold your answers with two types of rows

Note : you can limit the recycle to hold only for items just make getCount method return 4;

And inflate the row you need depending on what type of the answer either textView or ImageView

Thus, Set a listener on the ItemView to choose the answer.

That's it
Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `TextView` for both text and image, use `setText` for text answer and use `.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.smiley, 0, 0, 0);` for image answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution I wanted.  I will be using this to draw text as a drawable:

```
    ImageButton b= findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    Bitmap bm=Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p.setTextSize(48);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/aquariusno8cg.ttf");
    p.setTypeface(font);
    c.drawText("1e2e3e4e5e6e7e8e9e",0,224,p);
    Drawable testPaint = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bm);
    b.setImageDrawable(testPaint);
```